# Only 4 out of 12 halogen lights work after replacing a switch

Tags: halogen

I tried to replace a Lutron Maestro dimmer with  Legrand universal dimmer (for cosmetic purposes only - Lutron dimmer worked without any issues ). Once installed, the new Legrand dimmer only worked as a switch and didn’t produce a consistent flow of electricity (the lights were either too bright or flickering)…. So, I removed it, but in the process I blew something in the lamp - now only 4 out 12 lamps are working with the old Lurton dimmer (or a regular switch)… The light fixture consists of 2 rows of rope pendant lights with halogen bulbs, the 2 lights closest to the electrical wire on both rows are still turning on and can be dimmed with the old Lurton dimmer. The rest show no sign of life. Any suggestions on how to fix the this ? Thank you. Irene

Comment: `blew something in the lamp ` you blew up some lamps! switch working with not working to check.

Comment: Working with the breaker on never ends well.  A few lamps are cheap when compared to what could have happen.

Comment: if these are low voltage halogen from a transformer, you likely cannot use just any dimmer, and you'll blow more bulbs when your dimmer and transformer resonate again and induce voltage spikes.

Comment: Uh, what @crip659 says. From what you're saying you worked without the power turned off that feeds the circut related to that switch. If you're not a professional, and even if you are, that's not a good practice. Be glad it's only the bulbs and not yourself that has the problem.